# Drawing a Polygon on an NVD3 Line Chart with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am looking to draw a polygon about a line in an NVD3 line chart, that would look something like this to show how a line changed between two years:

[image: Line chart with added polygon]

The difficulty is that while I have no issue using the NVD3 built-in capabilities for creating the line, I cannot seem to figure out how to access the scales that it created for the chart so that data I plot on top using plain D3 matches the X and Y scales that already exist.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var chart;
var data;

d3.json("/data/someData.json", function(error, data) {

if (error) return console.warn(error);

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .options({
      transitionDuration: 300,
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      forceX: [5000],
      forceY: [.18, .52],
      showLegend: true,
      xScale: d3.scale.linear()
    });

  chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel("Income")
    .tickFormat(d3.format('$,.d'));

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('Average Tax (%)')
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.1%'));

  d3.select('#chart1').append('svg')
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;

});

});
```

What would I have to do to be able to draw on top of this chart?

Also, is there documentation around what javascript calls are made when there is a click on the legend items? I'd like to create buttons outside of the NVD3 chart that makes those same calls, but I can't find a reference to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep a reference to the chart object, the d3 scales are `chart.xScale()` and `chart.yScale()`.

To replicate the legend click function, you could steal the event handler function and execute it yourself.

```
var clickHandler = d3.select('.nv-series').on('click');
// it needs to be called with the chart data
var myData = d3.select('.nv-groups').data();
// toggle second series...
clickHandler(myData[0][1]);
```

This is a bit hacky though, and at some point, you might want to think about just doing the whole chart in straight `d3`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! I'll give this a try later to see if this works. Was really hoping that NVD3 would allow for a tighter integration with pure D3 - would allow me to spend time on the differences than reinventing a lot of what they've built.